# TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null but the id is correct as i have similarly called another form also

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute a function but this error keeps on coming in the console

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
> fetch http://localhost:8082/app.js:28368

Here is the HTML code

```
<form id="player2">
           <div class="form-group">
            <label>Player 2 - From address:</label>
            <input type=" type" class="form-control" id="fromAddress2">
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="player2" class="btn-primary" />
      
        </form>
```

Here is the App.js

```
function fetch(){
  
document.getElementById("player2").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
 var fromAddress2 = document.getElementById("#player2 #fromAddress2").value;

console.log(fromAddress2);

OraclizeContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {

  console.log("Initializing");
  instance.deposit({from: fromAddress2, 
                    gas: 3000000,
                    value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether')}) //betAmount is a input box and fetching its value into betamount variable and passing it over here
                               .then(function(v){
                                       console.log(v);
                                       console.log("Function Executed");

                                 });
                       }).then(function() {
                                              console.log("Testing");
                       }).catch(function(e) {
                                               console.log(e);
                       });

})
}
```

I have checked the ids but they are correct, cannot figure out why this is not working
Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: `document.getElementById` expects the `id` as a parameter. Not a selector.

Comment: For selectors use `document.querySelector()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var fromAddress2 = document.getElementById("#player2 #fromAddress2").value;
```

should be instead:

```
var fromAddress2 = document.querySelector("#player2 #fromAddress2").value;
```